# How to make Django render URL dispatcher from HTML in Pandas column, instead of forwarding raw HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, url, django-urls

I want to render a pandas dataframe in HTML, in which 1 column has URL dispatched links to other pages. If I try to render this HTML, it just keeps raw HTML, instead of converting the URLS:

`utils.py`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["2022-007", "2022-008", "2022-111", "2022-222", "2022-555", "2022-151"], columns=["column_of_interest"])
df["column_of_interest"] = df['column_of_interest'].apply(lambda x: '''<a href="{{% url 'columndetails' {0} %}}">{0}</a>'''.format(x)
df_html = generate_html(df)
context={"df" : df_html}

def generate_html(dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
    # get the table HTML from the dataframe
    table_html = dataframe.to_html(table_id="table", escape=False)
    # construct the complete HTML with jQuery Data tables
    # You can disable paging or enable y scrolling on lines 20 and 21 respectively
    html = f"""
    {table_html}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {{
            $('#table').DataTable({{
                // paging: false,    
                // scrollY: 400,
            }});
        }});
    </script>
    """
    # return the html
    return html
```

`views.py`

```
def column(request):
    context = get_context(request)
    return render(request, "database/column.html", context)

def columndetails(request, column_of_interest):
    return render(request, "/columndetails.html")
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('columndetails/<str:column_of_interest>/', views.labrequest_details, name="columndetails")]
```

`toprocess.html`

```
{% extends "database/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<br />
<div style="float: left;" class="container" id="labrequestoverview">
{{ df|safe }}
</div>
```

Everything shows normal, and the HTML is rendered almost as should, however the HTML is not being rendered by Django:
[image]

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'columndetails'%202022-007%25%7D
The current path, {% url 'columndetails' 2022-007%}, didn’t match any of these.
```

Is it possible to have Django render this HTML as it intended and not just forward it as raw HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you cannot use `{% url '' %}`.

To resolve a URL dynamically in your utils.py, use [build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) instead. You can also combine this with reverse() like so (note: you will have to pass your request object):

```py
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('columndetails', args=('2022-007', )))
```

Comment: You mean I can't use ```{% url '' %}``` in utils.py? I have proceeded with the reverse and absolute uri and this seems to work like a charm :)!

Comment: Correct! It's a template tag and thus only works in templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url